# Way to add Icons/Image in Lightning Combo-box in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I want to create UI in LWC, as per images shown below :

[image]

[image]

Those icons have to be dynamic (depending upon certain conditions those will change).
I created lightning combo-box, but I am not able to icons into it.

Can anyone suggest how can do it?
Combo-box is not compulsion, if it can be done through any other way, please let me know!

Comment: fyi: i cannot remove my downvote unless you modify your post.

Answer (score 2):

For any custom component, you can take the code reference from [lightning design system](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/picklist/).

Created a [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Q4GPbgG-i/3/edit) for you with sample code.

**Output:**

[image]
However note that you still need to handle events like ***open/close picklist, selection/deselection of options, etc.,.***